# unity call update function from event trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my game is based on event triggers and no frame dependent functions... but i want to implement some ui animation that is frame dependent... now the problem is i want to call this function from event trigger.

i searched up and found that i can have a trigger bool in the update function with if statement so it doesnt execute... when the event is triggered the bool changes to true executing the animation next frame onwards and switch it back to false after the animation has finished...

but still i wanted to ask if there is a better way to do this since i dont want to make the application call update function everytime...

Comment: How about using DoTween? http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php

Comment: [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/180101/do-empty-update-methods-get-executed-and-slow-down-the-game-while-playing) is a good post about performance cost of update, generally if it is not thousand of objects the cost is neglectable

Comment: Have your event to start a coroutine and that will act like an update.

Comment: Depends on your animation. If your animation is not a loop, you can use a trigger parameter to start the animation and simply at the end of the animation create an event that will call a function and inside the function simply reset your trigger. 
You can read more about it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html

Note: You can avoid the update method on the documentation an simply use OnTriggerEnter() method in your case

Comment: @PavlosMavris my bad for using animation and not defining it clearly... the ui objects move in my desired pattern according to a script and it is not exactly an "animation"... so i dont think i can use your suggestion...

Comment: @Everts thanks i looked into it and found it pretty useful... guess i will use this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 Scripts. One script for the Trigger-Function and one script for the Update-Function. Add both to an Object and disable the Script with the Update-Function.
When your event is triggered just enable the Update-Script and disable it after the animation has finished.

Comment: that is actually a good and practical one... so one method is coroutine and another is this... thanks for the response...